# How to maintain databases for local wordpress development when site is live?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have just started with WordPress development and I ran into a pretty big roadblock. I used MAMP to develop the site locally, and chose WPEngine as my host.

I created a theme that utilized plugins like Custom Post Types UI, and Advanced Custom Forms. For this reason, I had to upload my local MySQL database to the host to keep all the data those plugins relied on.

This is all great and dandy, but there must be a better way than managing a local MySQL database, adding data to it, and then exporting it to later import it in the production database. Is there something I'm missing with this workflow?

EDIT: I also have to perform a find & replace on the URLs each time I migrate the DB's, thats a huge pain

Comment: It is called deploy automation... And you should only add changes (migrations). Start with your current site as a base, and start adding features and document them. Then automate these additions. I can recommend Ansible for this.
I automated a deployment of Drupal + CiviCRM for a job interview, and it is really easy to use.
You will end with a Playbook with following roles for example: `Add New Theme` (With tasks `DownloadTheme`,`EnableTheme`, `Download and Install Custom Post Types UI`, `Enable Custom Post Types UI`, `Enable Advanced Custom Forms`, `Clear Cache`,  etc), `Migrate Database`

Comment: @JorgeeFG Thanks, I will definitely be looking into this!